# CakePHP & Foreign Key Constraint

Tags: cakephp, foreign-keys

I'm designing the DB for the first project with Cake and having problem with duplicated foreign key constraint.

I create the db model in mysql workbench, something like

**student table**
id/name/

**studentProfile table**
id/profile_value/student_id
Foreign Key: (`**student_id**`) Ref `student`.`id`

**student_class table**
student_id
class_id
Foreign Key:  (`**student_id**`) ref  `student`.`id`

**class table**
id/className

I got error#121 when insert into mysql.After reading, it's caused by the duplicated foreign key. (http://thenoyes.com/littlenoise/?p=81)

But as stated in cakephp's doc, foreign key = name of the related table followed by _id. So if there're multiple foreign keys pointing to the same field, there will be duplications.

> Foreign keys in hasMany, belongsTo or hasOne relationships are
>   recognized by default as the (singular) name of the related table
>   followed by _id. So if a Baker hasMany Cake, the cakes table will
>   refer to the bakers table via a baker_id foreign key. For a multiple
>   worded table like category_types, the foreign key would be
>   category_type_id.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Your tables should be called 'students', 'student_profiles', 'student_classes' & 'classes' unless you are intentionally overriding CakePHP's naming conventions.

Comment: right, that's one problem, but it's not the cause of the error121. any suggestion?

Comment: @RichardAtHome [classes_students](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started/cakephp-conventions.html#model-and-database-conventions)*

Comment: `I got error#121 when insert into mysql` please show some code **and the exact error message** demonstrating you doing that - that sql error is related to creating tables, which CakePHP doesn't do for you when creating data.

Answer (score -2):

plz use alias when you call same name FK

```
studentProfile.student_id and student_class.student_id
```